# Running on Android Studio on my Mac is becoming impossible

Tags: macos, android-studio

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro 13" with a 10th gen i5 and 8 gb of ram. Whenever I try to run android studio on my Mac. My life becomes a nightmare. If I even try to change some of the preferences, it just stops responding, and the weird part is that everything else keeps running perfectly, there are absolutely no issues with any other app running while android studio is frozen I am learning how to code and use such programs and I have no idea why this is happening when I've seen people use 6-7 year old MacBook Airs to run it and it works. I have no plugins installed, just the basic out-of-the-box settings. Can someone please help me.

Comment: upgrade your operating system

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I am already on the latest version there is, a.k.a Big Sur 11.1

Comment: Go to Help -> Show Logs in Explorer option and open the logs file. There you may check the error details and attach with question. There are other options as well which may help to get the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android Studio freezes on macOS Big Sur**

On machines running macOS Big Sur, Android Studio 4.1 might freeze when you open a dialog.

To work around this issue, do one of the following:

- Go to the Apple Menu, select **System Preferences > General**. In the
  **Prefer tabs when opening documents** option, select "never". Then
  restart Android Studio.
- Upgrade to Android Studio 4.2, currently available in the Beta channel.

As mentioned by [Android Studio Itself](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#ki-signed-apk-macos)

Comment: Would you suggest updating to the beta, or is it buggy and thus would be better to stay on version 4.1?